# Holomorphicity of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/{n^s}$ be the Riemann zeta function, $s\in \mathbb{C}$. I can show that it converges absolutely and uniformly on the right half-plane Re$(s)>1$.

How can I show that it is holomorphic there?

For example, is there a theorem which states that a uniform limit of a sequence of holomorphic functions defined in a region of the complex plane is itself holomorphic?

Comment: "For example, is there a theorem ..." Yes, the limit of a _locally uniformly_ convergent sequence of holomorphic functions is holomorphic.

Comment: So are you saying that given any $z$, Re$(z)>1$ there is an open disc centered at $z$ on which the partial sums of $\zeta(s)$ converge uniformly? Also where can I find the theorem you quoted?

Comment: For $s = \sigma + it$, you have $\lvert n^{-s}\rvert = \lvert e^{-s\log n}\rvert = e^{-\operatorname{Re}(s\log n)} = e^{-\sigma\log n} = n^{-\sigma}$, so the convergence is uniform in every closed half plane $\{\operatorname{Re} s \geqslant \sigma\}$ with $\sigma > 1$. The theorem is a part of a theorem of Weierstraß (that also states the locally uniform convergence of all derivatives if the sequence is locally uniformly convergent), or follows easily from Morera's theorem. Any book on Complex Analysis provides a proof (or it is worth _not_ having).

Comment: @MarkRodriguez - I am struggling with the same point you raise in your comment. The theorems I am pointed to refer to uniform convergence on open compact sets ... not the half plane $\Re(z)>1$. Daniel - is the answer that there are two separate theorems, or that the uniform convergence is true for any compact domain within the larger domain $\Re(z)>1$ ? Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic on the half plane $Re (s)>1$. By Morera's theorem it suffices to show that $\int_{\gamma} \zeta(s)dz=0$ for all closed contours $\gamma$ on this half-plane.
But this follows easily from Cauchy's theorem, and the fact that we can swap integral 
and sum (Weierstrass M-test):
$$
\int_{\gamma} \zeta(z)dz = \int_{\gamma}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^z}dz=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{n^z}dz=0.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quote of Theorem 1 from chapter 5 of Ahlfors' text:

"Suppose that $f_n(z)$ is analytic in the region $\Omega_n$, and that the sequence $\{f_n(z)\}$ converges to a limit function $f(z) $in a region $\Omega$, uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$. Then $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Omega$. Moreover, $f_n'(z)$ converges uniformly to $f'(z)$ on every compact subset of $\Omega$."

I think it will be helpful.

Comment: How are $\Omega_n$ and $\omega_n$ related? THanks

Comment: $\Omega$ is the region of convergence of the sequence $\{ f_n(z) \}$, while $\Omega_n$ is the domain of analyticity of $f_n$. For your case you can take both the $\Omega_n$'s and $\Omega$ to be the right half plane $\Re s>1$

Comment: Sorry I meant $\Omega_n$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: First of all the "tail" $\cap_{n=N}^\infty \Omega_n$ shouldn't be empty for large enough $N$, so that we can talk about the limit. $\Omega$ is then a subset of that tail.